# jQuery iCheck callback

Tags: jquery, plugins, icheck

I'm using Jquery iCheck to style input fields and I came to a point where I can not really handle the callback from iCheck. What I want to retrive, all checked input values inside  container with a given class name

http://jsfiddle.net/lgtsfiddler/E4bKg/1/
here is what I have been trying but the clicked elemnt on flow is not going to be pushed in array just on the second click.

```
  <ul class="brands">
        <li>
            <input class ="marken" type="checkbox" name="brand" value="brand1">
            <label>brand1</label>
        </li>
        <li>
             <input class ="marken" type="checkbox" name="brand" value="brand1">
            <label>brand2</label>
        </li>
        <li>
             <input class ="marken" type="checkbox" name="brand" value="brand1">
            <label>brand3</label>
        </li>
        <li>
             <input class ="marken" type="checkbox" name="brand" value="brand1">
            <label>brand4</label>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Code:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     //here I style with iCheck
     $('ul.brands input').each(function () {
         var self = $(this),
             label = self.next(),
             label_text = label.text();

         label.remove();
         self.iCheck({
             checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_line-blue',
             radioClass: 'iradio_line',
             insert: '<div class="icheck_line-icon"></div>' + label_text
         });
     });

     //Register click event
     $('ul.brands input').on('ifClicked', function (event) {
         brands();
     });
 });
 //here I try to retrieve all checked values
 function brands() {
     var brands = [];
     $('ul.brands li div.icheckbox_line-blue').each(function (index, value) {
         var attr_class = $(value).attr('class');
         console.log(attr_class);
         //check if icheckbox_line-blue class contains checked  
         if (attr_class.indexOf("checked") !== -1) {
             brands.push($(value).find('input').val());
         }
     });
     console.log(brands);
 }
```

so how to check this class after was checked?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of checking classes you can check the original checkbox, and get the button description from the parent.

Side note, I use `ifToggled` event so it will be fired for checked and unchecked elements.

Code:

```
$('ul.brands input').each(function () {
    var self = $(this),
        label = self.next(),
        label_text = label.text();

    label.remove();
    self.iCheck({
        checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_line-blue',
        radioClass: 'iradio_line',
        insert: '<div class="icheck_line-icon"></div>' + label_text
    });
});

$('ul.brands input').on('ifToggled', function (event) {
    brands();
});

function brands() {
    var brands = [];
    $('ul.brands input').each(function (index, value) {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            brands.push($(this).parent().text());
        }
    });
    console.log(brands);
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/S2NdY/

Comment: you know you help me a lot with this issue

Comment: Irvin, have you tried setting setting the `checked` property of inputs? Doesn't seem that's the case. `is(:checked)` returns true but checkbox doesn't get sent as checked when the form is submitted.

Comment: what if my ul's classes are dynamic? @Irvin Dominin